# Calling rows.Err() in a multiple result set query with rows.NextResultSet()

Tags: go

I'm building a query with multiple result sets, following the example given, [here](https://golang.org/src/database/sql/example_test.go). Important bits copied below for convenience.

My question is, should `rows.Err()` be called after each `for rows.Next() {...}` loop, rather than once at the very end as shown in the example? Why / why not? My understanding is that `rows.Err()` will catch errors, ["... encountered during iteration"](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Err), whereas `rows.NextResultSet()` will catch, ["... [errors] advancing to [the next result set]"](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.NextResultSet). Seems like I would want to catch errors during each iteration, no? Thanks!

```
rows, err := db.Query(q, age)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer rows.Close()

for rows.Next() {
    var (
        id   int64
        name string
    )
    if err := rows.Scan(&id, &name); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("id %d name is %s\n", id, name)
}
if !rows.NextResultSet() {
    log.Fatal("expected more result sets", rows.Err())
}
var roleMap = map[int64]string{
    1: "user",
    2: "admin",
    3: "gopher",
}
for rows.Next() {
    var (
        id   int64
        role int64
    )
    if err := rows.Scan(&id, &role); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("id %d has role %s\n", id, roleMap[role])
}
if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find from source code of `Next` or `Err` or `NextResultSet` function that there is `lasterr` member of `Rows` structure which can be set by several ways and `Err` always return it if it isn't `EOF`.

Those ways are:

1. `Next` gets some error, sets `lasterr` and always returns `false` (so `for rows.Next() {...` doesn't iterate more and it is enough to check `rows.Err()` only after the loop.
2. `NextResultSet` also sets `lasterr` whenever it gets error and also returns `false`.

So answer is yes, it should. Because if `NextResultSet` after `Next` returns `false` its error replaces error from `Next`.